# What is "instrumentation" in the context of SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In [SQLAlchemy's tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html), it mentions "instrumentation" but doesn't appear to properly define what instrumentation is:

> These class attributes exist as Python descriptors, and define
>   instrumentation for the mapped class. The functionality of this instrumentation includes the ability to fire on change events, track modifications, and to automatically
>   load new data from the database when needed.

What is instrumentation in this context?

Comment: Was asking the same question about instrumentation events http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/events.html#module-sqlalchemy.orm.instrumentation but googling yielded no useful result as keywords are very generic. Thanks for asking this question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

instrumentation is the process of attaching attributes to a class, which are implemented as [Python Descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) (this link is mentioned in that sentence) such that any attribute get, set, or delete operation, that is:

```
# __get__
print myobject.someattribute

# __set__
myobject.someattribute = "foo"

# __del__
del myoject.someattribute
```

... will invoke Python code for each event, rather than using Python's default behavior of accessing/manipulating `myobject.__dict__` directly.   SQLAlchemy takes advantage of these hooks to provide behaviors such as [lazy loading](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/lazyLoad.html), as well as to record when the value of an attribute changes, for the purpose of implementing the [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern, where only those elements that have changed are rolled into UPDATE statements to be emitted to the database upon flush.